# Why Xcode Simulator doesn't render SwiftUI TextViews the same width as on a real device

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am developing my first SwiftUI app and get a weird issue.
My configuration is : MacBook Pro with Catalina 10.15.4 ; Xcode 11.4.
I build and run my app with Simulator for iPhone 8 - iOS 13.4. The app works well.
Then I build and run my app with Simulator for iPhone 8Plus - iOS 13.4. The app works well.
Then I build and run my app on my personal iPhone 8Plus - iOS 13.4. The app looks different. Some Text views are truncated on the Home screen and on the List screen.
Why does it work on the Simulator (for same size or smaller size) and not on the real device ?

To investigate the problem, with the Simulator, I made some screenshots. With the File Inspector, I checked the Image sizes.
For the iPhone 8, the Image size says 750x1334 pixels. No surprise as it is the expected rendered resolution.
For the iPhone 8 Plus, the Image size says 1242x2208 pixels. Surprise ! Never seen this size before. Any clue ?
Taking now the Simulator for iPhone 11, Image size says 828x1792 pixels. No surprise neither.
So why the image size is not the expected rendered size for the iPhone 8 Plus (eg. 1080x1920) ?
Does it mean I run in fact a larger (than iPhone 8 Plus) simulator ?
I would appreciate any assistance.
[on my iPhone 8 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9G8u.png)

Comment: We can’t really help you if you don’t show the problematic code.

Comment: Check out https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions for what iPhone screen sizes are. 1242x2208 is in fact the correct resolution of the plus-size phones.

Comment: Gereon is correct. I took out my data out from https://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/apple-iphone-product-line-comparison which is wrong for the Plus series.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why a smaller screen size is able to render the Text views correctly and a larger screen is not. That's the reason why I developed on an iPhone 8 and not on a larger screen. Any clue ?

Comment: I'm afraid that without code no one will be able to help.